# Некорректное поведение кнопки в кастомной ячейке UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

У меня есть таблица с кастомными ячейками. Каждая ячейка содержит кнопку, которая ставит метку(при нажатии на кнопку  заголовок кнопки сменяется с 0 на 1)
Проблема состоит в том, что при нажатии на кнопку одной ячейки меняется надпись еще в одной которая стоит через 3-4-5 ячеек от текущей("Отступ" зависит от размера экрана айфона)
Не вижу в этом никакой логики и не понимаю, как это вообще возможно.
Прошу помочь разобраться с этой проблемой.
Привожу код:

```
@IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!  //в классе кастомной ячейки  
@IBAction func likeBtn(sender: UIButton)//действие при нажатии
{
    var likeCount: Int = Int((likeButton.titleLabel?.text)!)!
    if !likePressed
    {
        likeCount += 1;
        likeButton.setTitle("\(likeCount)", forState: .Normal)
        likePressed = true
    }
    else if likePressed
    {
        likeCount -= 1;
        likeButton.setTitle("\(likeCount)", forState: .Normal)
        likePressed = false      
    }
}
```

Создание ячеек:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cellID = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
....
}
```

Comment: Для начала конечно же Вам следует разобраться как работает таблица и ячейки. Ячейки в таблице `Reusable`, что говорит о том, что когда таблица скроллиться, ячейки не создаются заново, а используются те, что уже были нарисованы.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeObject {
    var likes = 0
    var likedByThisUser = false {
        didSet {
            if likedByThisUser {
                likes += 1
            } else {
                likes -= 1
            }
        }
    }
}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var someObject: SomeObject
    @IBAction func likeButtonPressed(likeButton: UIButton) {
        someObject.likedByThisUser = !someObject.likedByThisUser
        likeButton.image = someObject.likedByThisUser ? UIImage("heartFilled") : UIImage("heartEmpty")
    }
}

class CustomTableView: UITableViewController {
    var someObjects: [SomeObject] = []

    //...

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.someObject = someObjects[indexPath.row]
        //...
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используются reusable ячейки, поэтому данное поведение (в котором вы не видите никакой логики :)) вполне корректно. Реализуйте метод UITableViewCell - prepareForReuse, в котором будете обнулять title кнопки, и все будет отлично, для этого нужно создать класс ячейки (как сабкласс UITableViewCell), установить его в сториборде на ячейку. В данном сабклассе нужно переопределить метод prepareForReuse. Пробуйте, тестируйте - все получится!